# Can I ask for creating a new tag as I do not have the sufficient reputation

Tags: feature-request, tags, questions

While posting a question on Apache-Kafka I wanted to add `Apache-Kafka` as tag, however I was not able to do so as the tag was not created in https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ . Is there any way I can ask for this new tag to be created ?

Comment: You want to ask this on http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/ instead; but I'd leave off the tag, and let someone else create it if they feel it is needed still.

Comment: Just ask the question, and leave a comment asking other people to edit it in.

Comment: Generally, new tags should meet a demonstrated need (i.e. apply to multiple existing (on-topic) questions).  Are there other posts on Programmers about Apache-Kafka to which the tag could be applied?  If so, then asking on Meta.Programmers.SE would be appropriate so someone could create it and apply it to the other questions as well.

Comment: Quoting from [*What are tags, and how should I use them?*](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/tagging): *As a general rule, you should avoid creating new tags if possible*.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: except this is for Programmers.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about tagging on Programmers.SE, ask on http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, is there any way to do it or should I just post the same question in meta.programmers as u mentioned

Comment: @user2720864: you'd have to repost; but I don't think there is much point in asking as the answer will be the same: don't.

Comment: @user2720864 before asking, you need to find other questions that it can be applied too.  Creating a tag for 1 question is not encouraged.